# Grails domain functions not working

Tags: function, grails, intellij-idea

I problem that seems to be fairly simple but has me stumped since yesterday afternoon. My domain class functions don't work (saving and retrieving records). Using intellij Idea, auto completion still detects the domain fields though so if I type "`myDomain.`" after declaring an object, auto complete will still suggest domain properties though. Anyhow, here's what I got:

**Controller:**

```
def update(){
    switch(request.getMethod()){
         case 'POST':
             if(params.fire == 'true'){
                 def oldClients = Clients.findAll() /* This is where it breaks. Also 
                 note that all other methods of retrieving data doesn't work either,
                 as well as trying to create and save new records. */
             }
             break
    }
}
```

**Domain:**

```
// I shortened the domain coz the original has a buttload of fields.
class Clients {
    String CClientId
    String CFirstName
    String CSurname
    String CEmail

    static mapping = {
        id name: "CClientId", generator: "assigned"
        version false
        datasource "dataSourceOld"
        cache usage: 'read-only'
    }

    static constraints = {
        CClientId(maxSize: 12)
        CFirstName(nullable: true, maxSize: 5)
        CSurname(maxSize: 30)
        CEmail(maxSize: 30)
    }
}
```

Something else to note is that when I try to declare the domain's constraints the other way, i.e `CClientId maxSize: 12` instead of how I declared it above I get the `cannot resolve symbol` error on `CClientId` and the `';', '}' or new line expected` error on the colon following `maxSize`,

**Here's the error** I get when I try to run my update action:

```
.Error 
|
2016-06-28 09:42:02,741 [http-bio-7070-exec-10] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingMethodException occurred when processing request: [POST] /oneyeargift/adminhome/updateAbases - parameters:
fire: true
No signature of method: unipoint.oyg.domain.old.ClientsOyg.findAll() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: findAll(), findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), findAll(java.lang.Object), findAll(java.lang.String), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure). Stacktrace follows:
Message: No signature of method: unipoint.oyg.domain.old.ClientsOyg.findAll() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: findAll(), findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), findAll(java.lang.Object), findAll(java.lang.String), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)
    Line | Method
->>   -2 | newInstance0                    in sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     39 | newInstance                     in     ''
|     27 | newInstance . . . . . . . . . . in sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl
|    513 | newInstance                     in java.lang.reflect.Constructor
|    991 | jlrConstructorNewInstance . . . in org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor
|     77 | invoke                          in org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor
|     71 | doConstructorInvoke . . . . . . in     ''
|     42 | callConstructor                 in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite
|     57 | defaultCallConstructor . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray
|    182 | callConstructor                 in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite
|    194 | callConstructor . . . . . . . . in     ''
|     -1 | findAll                         in unipoint.oyg.domain.old.ClientsOyg$$EPpP6s0O
|     45 | defaultCall . . . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray
|    108 | call                            in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite
|    112 | call . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    880 | updateAbases                    in unipoint.oyg.control.admin.AdminhomeController$$EPpP3IMS
|     -2 | invoke0 . . . . . . . . . . . . in sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl
|     39 | invoke                          in     ''
|     25 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
|    597 | invoke                          in java.lang.reflect.Method
|    122 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReloadedTypeInvoker$2
|   1288 | jlrMethodInvoke                 in org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor
|     69 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.MixedGrailsControllerHelper
|     -1 | invoke                          in grails.plugin.cache.web.ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper
|    348 | handleAction . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper
|     -1 | handleAction                    in grails.plugin.cache.web.ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper
|    231 | executeAction . . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper
|     -1 | executeAction                   in grails.plugin.cache.web.ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper
|    197 | handleURI . . . . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper
|     -1 | handleURI                       in grails.plugin.cache.web.ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper
|    118 | handleURI . . . . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper
|     -1 | handleURI                       in grails.plugin.cache.web.ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper
|     72 | handleRequest . . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController
|     48 | handle                          in org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter
|    328 | doDispatch . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet
|    852 | doService                       in org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
|    882 | processRequest . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet
|    789 | doPost                          in     ''
|    646 | service . . . . . . . . . . . . in javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
|    727 | service                         in     ''
|    305 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    210 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    200 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     -1 | doFilter                        in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.ehcache.EhcachePageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|    346 | invokeDelegate                  in org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
|    259 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    243 | internalDoFilter                in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    210 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     70 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    243 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    210 | doFilter                        in     ''
|     70 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    243 | internalDoFilter                in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    210 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     70 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    243 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    210 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    749 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher
|    487 | processRequest                  in     ''
|    412 | doForward . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    339 | forward                         in     ''
|    318 | forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils
|    283 | forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo in     ''
|    274 | forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo in     ''
|    203 | doFilterInternal                in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter
|     76 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    243 | internalDoFilter                in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    210 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     82 | doFilterInternal                in com.linkedin.grails.profiler.ProfilerFilter
|     76 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    243 | internalDoFilter                in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    210 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    206 | obtainContent                   in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter
|    152 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    243 | internalDoFilter                in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    210 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     -1 | call                            in javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter
|     45 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.grails.plugin.resource.DevModeSanityFilter
|    243 | internalDoFilter                in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    210 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    369 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    109 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor
|     83 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    381 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     97 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter
|    381 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     78 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|    381 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    119 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter
|    381 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     54 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
|    381 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    187 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter
|     40 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|    381 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     79 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.MutableLogoutFilter
|    381 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     79 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
|    381 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    168 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy
|    346 | invokeDelegate                  in org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
|    259 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    243 | internalDoFilter                in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    210 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    113 | doFilter                        in io.jdev.miniprofiler.servlet.ProfilingFilter
|    243 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    210 | doFilter                        in     ''
|     69 | doFilterInternal . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter
|     76 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    243 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    210 | doFilter                        in     ''
|     66 | doFilterInternal . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter
|     76 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    243 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    210 | doFilter                        in     ''
|     88 | doFilterInternal . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
|     76 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    346 | invokeDelegate . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
|    259 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    243 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    210 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    222 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
|    123 | invoke                          in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve
|    171 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve
|     99 | invoke                          in org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve
|    118 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve
|    408 | service                         in org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter
|   1023 | process . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor
|    589 | process                         in org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler
|    312 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor
|    895 | runTask                         in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|    918 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
^    662 | run                             in java.lang.Thread
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Double check if you have class in right packages (class in domain). Double check if you have right import (if you didn't import Clients from different package). Double check if your directories of classes are corresponding to package names.

Comment: All of those are correct

Comment: Is it a typo or it's your real constraint section? Instead of `String CFirstName(nullable: true, maxSize: 5)` you should have `CFirstName(nullable: true, maxSize: 5)` (without type)

Comment: Those are typos, my bad

Comment: Did you try a clean/removal of the target directory, and try again?

Comment: ps: your naming of objects is quite confusing. Don't call a Client `Clients`, and checking for the request method in the update method should also not be needed, use URLMappings for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because of the way you have named the attributes of the domain class.
Have you tried to do the following?

```
class Clients {
    String cClientId
    String cFirstName
    String cSurname
    String cEmail

    static mapping = {
        id name: "cClientId", generator: "assigned"
        version false
        datasource "dataSourceOld"
        cache usage: 'read-only'
    }

    static constraints = {
        cClientId(maxSize: 12)
        cFirstName(nullable: true, maxSize: 5)
        cSurname(maxSize: 30)
        cEmail(maxSize: 30)
    }
}
```

Thus if you declare constraints as follows:

```
static constraints = {
    cClientId maxSize: 12
    cFirstName nullable: true, maxSize: 5
    cSurname maxSize: 30
    cEmail maxSize: 30
}
```

It's works ;)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like Grails does not recognise your Clients as a domain object and that's why all the GORM dynamic methods (get, list, find, save, update...) did not work.

Comment: That's indeed his problem, but not an answer.